# How do I tell a page to ignore internal CSS in favor of external CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-specificity

Background: I'm updating the style of a page in a Rails app (the rails part shouldn't be relevant to this question, I hope), and I've added internal CSS in a style tag. Now I have the main parts of the page looking how I want them to look, but the bootstrap navbar also received the CSS changes, so the font size and many other aspects of the navbar are now changed, causing inconsistency with the rest of the site.

Question: Is there a way to tell the page not to apply the internal style to the navbar so it uses the external style instead?

Comment: other than using `!important`, you can't. inline css has a higher precedence than external css.

Comment: I believe the OP is using styles written directly into the HTML page (i.e. in a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` not inline styles like `<div style=".....">`

Comment: "Specificity" is the word of the day here. You'd do well to study a bit. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Yes, @JRulle is right, I'm using CSS in a style tag.

Comment: @isherwood, I will get to reading, thanks for the link. I was literally thrown on this 3 days ago with no CSS knowledge, so any help is always welcome!

Comment: We take "agile" way too seriously here, just wait until the cannons are installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulate your internal CSS inside of another class*.
i.e. add a unique class to the container than holds all of your "main parts of the page" and then append that class to precede the selectors you write internal to the page

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/ru14t7ha/)** (example below)

```
a { color: green; } /* this style applies to all plain a tags */
.xyz a { color: red; } /* this style only applies to a tags within an xyz class */

<div class="nav">
  <a>I am a green link</a>
</div>
<div class="xyz">
  <a>This is a red link</a>
</div>
```

*as @isherwood mentions above, this would be leveraging [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for your purposes

Answer (score 2):

I came up with these two solutions:

The **first** solution is manage an order of links. The latest definition will be applied to a page:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
```

main.css:

```
body {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Then the page's body will be red backgrounded.

The **second** solution is just delete a `<style>` element using JQuery or whatever.

**P.S.**: I am not sure about the second solution's quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS The `!important` Rule on your classes in the external css file, look at the example below

```css
.myclass {
  color: blue!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p style="color:red;" class="myclass">This is currently using external css </p>


</body>
</html>
```